# cannot write a mutation with an array of strings

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma-graphql

Cannot use set in graphql playground with list scalar type.

I have created my Prisma datamodel.graphql and deployed it. One of the fields in my Exercise type is a list of movements. I used the list scalar type to define this field, and wrote the accompanying mutation in my mutation.js file. When I try to add a new exercise in my graphql playground I get this error.

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$_v0_data\" got invalid value {\"name\":\"split squat 3\",\"movement\":[\"push\",\"pull\"],\"liked\":false}; Field \"0\" is not defined by type ExerciseCreatemovementInput at value.movement.\nVariable \"$_v0_data\" got invalid value {\"name\":\"split squat 3\",\"movement\":[\"push\",\"pull\"],\"liked\":false}; Field \"1\" is not defined by type ExerciseCreatemovementInput at value.movement.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createExercise"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the mutation i wrote in graphql playground.

```
mutation {
  createExercise(
    name: "split squat 3"
    movement: ["push", "pull"]
    liked: false
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Here is the datamodel.graphql file.

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
}

# model for exercises
type Exercise {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  movement: [String!]!
  liked: Boolean
  video: String
}
```

When I write the mutation without any strings and just an empty array like this,

```
mutation {
  createExercise(
    name: "split squat 3"
    movement: []
    liked: false
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

everything works just fine and the exercise is added as a new node.

When I try to write the mutation with set like this,

```
mutation {
  createExercise(
    name: "split squat 3"
    movement: {set: ["push","pull"]}
    liked: false
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I get an error as well.

I can log into prisma.io and add the strings to the array by manually creating a new node.

Im not sure why I cannot add a list of strings in my mutation. =

Comment: Hi, could you share the part in your generated schema.graphql where there is `ExerciseCreatemovementInput ` ?

Comment: input ExerciseCreatemovementInput {
  set: [String!]
}}

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a separate input just like in the prisma schema.

```
input ExcerciseCreatemovementInput{
  set: [String!]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`movement: {set: ["push","pull"]}` is working for me.